# Tasker profile always get loop

Tags: tasker, lg, lg-g2, profiles

im new to tasker and want to set a profile. I made a profile when 8pm to 10pm + open android central app, will run task to launch filter app. In the filter app run shell to hit on button and hit "back" button to AC app. But when back to AC app my task always loop and open filter app again. Any suggestion how to make this profile stay untill im done using AC app? Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities: set the `Cooldown Time` for the profile to greater than two hours. Or, have the task which controls the filter app set a variable when it's done, set the profile to ensure that variable isn't set, add an exit task to the profile that clears the variable.